# how to make a horizontal swipe able card

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

[image]

I am working on an app using ionic and i want to reproduce something similar to this horizontal scrolling card but i am quite lost as  is not my solution. I am wondering if someone has been able to do something similar should shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ion-slide-box](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/) .

You can customize the border,width, etc. For example I make invisible for:

```
.slider-pager {
    display:none !important;
}
```

And add border, fix the margin:

```
.slider-slide {
    padding-top: 80px;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 200px !important;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 62px 56px
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Have a nice coding and make your own custom style!